# Functional library mixed with generators

Tags: ecmascript-6

I would like to ask if there is a way to mix generators and functional libraries like Ramda for example.

In Ramda I can do this:

```
R.range(1,100) //-> [0...99]
```

However I want to make the list lazy evaluated with generators.

For example if I want to take the first 10 like this sudo code:

```
take(10, range(1, 100)
```

However in ramda the full array will be made.

And the generators are hard to compose with regular functions.

If I want to pass generator it doesnt work:

```
const rng = function*(){
  for(i=0;i<100000;i++)yield i;
}
R.take(10, rng())
```

It returns []

In general is there good way to mix FP libraries with generators to create lazy lists

Comment: What exactly returns an empty list ?

Comment: https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20rng%20%3D%20function%2A%28%29%7B%0A%20%20for%28i%3D0%3Bi%3C100000%3Bi%2B%2B%29yield%20i%3B%0A%7D%0AR.take%2810%2C%20rng%28%29%29

Comment: It should accept iterable as second parameter - generators are iterable

Answer (score 1):

For this exact problem I made this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ramda-generators

Hopefully it's what you are looking for: lazy evaluation of streams in functional JavaScript

Comment: That's cool, but I wonder if both words can be made with one library like in haskell. Otherwise two libraries should be mixed which is not perfect world. For example somehow to abstract "Arrays" without knowing if the data is array or generator. But in practice it's very hard because generators when finished you cannot iterate over them more than once and some other differences.

Comment: Indeed this is one of the problems I'm trying to overcome to at least have a interoperability between Ramda and my library. At least for now most of the functions should work as supertset of Ramda functions, at least in theory

Answer (score 0):

It looks line RamdaJS' [`take` method](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#take) does not accept iterators. Looking at the source code, the [`take` method](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/d6558dd2b8136af1ffcda4c9b4c54f14f27324f4/source/take.js) uses a "home-made" [`slice method`](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/d6558dd2b8136af1ffcda4c9b4c54f14f27324f4/source/slice.js) that calls [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice). Sadly, `slice` only works on arrays, not iterators.

It is not possible to "lazy evaluate" like you would like it to do. However, you can create a method that will lazily generate your array, if you give the limits. The way to do that however, depends on your exact use case.

Comment: But that way I cannot use Ramda functions (or at least take). But I should create my own take, map, filter, functions only to use generators and lazy lists?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do with Ramda.

Comment: I want Ramda to work with my generators, that's what I want.